# Python 3 : from a string list to an int list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why am I getting this error?

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ab'
```

It happens when try to change a *string* list into an *int* list.

```
x = [["a","b"], ["c"]]
y = []

for i in x:
    answer = ''.join(i)
    y.append(answer)

final_value = [int(n) for n in y] #the error comes from here
print(final_value)
```

What should I do in order to make it work?

Comment: You are trying to cast string values (`"ab"` and `"c"`), that are not integers, to an integer value and this will result in an error. What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: my bad, I thought I wrote 1,2 and 3, sorry.

Comment: What made you think "a" can be converted into an integer?

Comment: @ozgur Yeah checked for the code for 1 hour and didn't see that I wrote a, b and c instead of 1 2 and 3...

Comment: Happens to the best of us @Sia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're trying to pass the built-in `int()` function a string (`"ab"`) that contains characters that cannot be converted to an integer. Out of curiosity what were you expecting `int("ab")` to return?

Converting a list of strings to a list of ints would work if all of your strings could be converted to integers like this:

```
x = [["1","11"], ["101"]]
y = []

for i in x:
    answer = ''.join(i)
    y.append(answer)

final_value = [int(n) for n in y] #the error comes from here
print(final_value)
```

This will print

```
[111, 101]
```